# Сессия не убивается session_destroy()

Tags: php, сессия

Дело такое. Имеется класс user в котором имеются методы авторизации и выхода. Проблема начинается когда идет переход на страницу с выполнением функционала выхода - выдается ошибка "Warning: session_destroy(): Session object destruction failed". Но если тупо обновить эту страницу, то ошибки не происходит. Однако если закинуть session_destroy() в метод авторизации то проблем нет вообще.  Единственная разница в работе механики методов в том, что на авторизацию идет запрос post. а на выход get. Я это тоже учел и сделал кнопку выхода через post, но все равно та же ошибка. А в целом методы практически одинаковы и проходят одни и те же процессы. Что может вызывать эту дурацкую ошибку?

Методы авторизации

```
public  static function authProcess()
    {

        system::stopRender();
        $login=$_POST['login'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $rq=db::query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$login' AND BINARY `password`='$password' limit 1");
        if(db::numRows($rq))
        {
            $data=db::toObject($rq);
            $_SESSION['SYSTEM_USER']=$data->id; 
        }
        system::redirect();
    }
```

и выхода.

```
public  static function exitProcess()
    {
        system::stopRender();       
        session_destroy();
        system::redirect();
    }
```

Comment: В сессии висят несохраненные данные. Попробуйте обнулить сессию пустым массивом.

Comment: @Etki, видел такой совет. Не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($_SESSION['имя сессии']); ?
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.